# Draw a box in two pivot (square not rectangle!)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i'm new in pine script.
In trading view, when we want to draw a box manually, when we hold the shift key and draw the box, it is drawn as a square. How can I draw this square box between the high/low in PineScript? is this even possible?
[just like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lj5W.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as square because scale of price and date axis can be changed and it will become rectangle. Even if you draw square manually it will change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the box.new object for this
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_box{dot}new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_box%7Bdot%7Dnew)

Comment: sir, thanks for your comment but how can i draw a "square" box?